# Occasional PostgreSQL "Duplicate key value violates unique constraint" error from Go insert

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a table with the unique constraint

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "bd_hash_index" ON "public"."bodies" USING btree ("hash");
```

I also have a Go program that takes "body" values on a channel, filters out the duplicates by hashing, and inserts only the non-duplicates into the database.
Like this:

```
import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/hex"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

type Process struct {
    DB                  *sql.DB
    BodiesHash          map[string]bool
    Channel             chan BodyIterface
    Logger              *log.Logger
}

func (pr *Process) Run() {
    bodyInsert, err := pr.DB.Prepare("INSERT INTO bodies (hash, type, source, body, created_timestamp) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)")
    if err != nil {
        pr.Logger.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer bodyInsert.Close()

    hash := md5.New()

    for p := range pr.Channel {
        nowUnix := time.Now().Unix()

        bodyString := strings.Join([]string{
            p.GetType(),
            p.GetSource(),
            p.GetBodyString(),
        }, ":")
        hash.Write([]byte(bodyString))
        bodyHash := hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil))
        hash.Reset()

        if _, ok := pr.BodiesHash[bodyHash]; !ok {
            pr.BodiesHash[bodyHash] = true

            _, err = bodyInsert.Exec(
                bodyHash,
                p.GetType(),
                p.GetSource(),
                p.GetBodyString(),
                nowUnix,
            )
            if err != nil {
                pr.Logger.Println(err, bodyString, bodyHash)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

But periodically I get the error

> "pq: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "bd_hash_index""

in my log file. I can't image how it can be, because I check the hash for uniqueness before I do an insert.
I am sure that when I call `go processDebugBody.Run()` the bodies table is empty.

The channel was created as a buffered channel with:

```
    processDebugBody.Channel = make(chan BodyIterface, 1000)
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicate hashes ?

Comment: I am sure that when i call `go processDebugBody.Run()` table `bodies` is empty.

Comment: The table may be empty, but the records you insert may have repeating hashes. Have you checked that ?

Comment: If different records have a same hash, it meant nothing, becase i check hash before call insert `if _, ok := pr.BodiesHash[bodyHash]; !ok`. So, if bodyHash already exist, i don't call insert function.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual values being inserted by the process, and the value of the hash that is being tested for its presence in the table?

Comment: I check postgres log and app log - hash is equal. But in postgres log i notice strange message before dublicate error occured: `2015-05-13 20:12:42 CEST LOG:  SSL renegotiation failure
2015-05-13 20:12:42 CEST ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "bd_hash_index"
2015-05-13 20:12:42 CEST DETAIL:  Key (hash)=(ec5d075f7ccbecdadb06e8bedc884089) already exists.
2015-05-13 20:12:42 CEST STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO bodies (hash, type, source, body, created_timestamp) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)`

Comment: Can it be a reason? `2015-05-13 20:12:42 CEST LOG: SSL renegotiation failure`. All time, when i found dublicate error, this row stand before it.

Comment: If you run in autocommit client you can send insertion and not receive state. so actual insert happens, but client does not have result, so it retries after reconnect

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html try setting it OFF and use begin; insert;commit; instead

Comment: BTW2, one of the reasons to use a `bool` map (rather than the smaller map of `struct{}`) as a set is to make the existence check a simple `if pr.BodiesHash[bodyHash]` without needing the longer comma ok form.

Answer (score 1):

When you execute a query outside of transaction with `sql.DB`, it automatically retries when there's a problem with connection. In the current implementation, up to 10 times. For example, notice `maxBadConnRetries` in [`sql.Exec`](http://golang.org/src/database/sql/sql.go?s=23335:23404#L861).

Now, it really happens only when underlying driver returns `driver.ErrBadConn` and specification states the following:

> ErrBadConn should be returned by a driver to signal to the sql package that a driver.Conn is in a bad state (such as the server having earlier closed the connection) and the **sql package should retry** on a new connection.
>
> **To prevent duplicate operations**, ErrBadConn should NOT be returned if there's a possibility that the database server might have performed the operation.

I think driver implementations are a little bit careless in implementing this rule, but maybe there is some logic behind it. I've been studying implementation of `lib/pq` the other day and noticed this scenario would be possible.

As you pointed out in the comments you have some SSL errors issued just before seeing duplicates, so this seems like a reasonable guess.

One thing to consider is to use transactions. If you lose the connection before committing the transaction, you can be sure it will be rolled back. Also the statements of the transactions are not retransmitted automatically on bad connections, so this problem might be solved – you will most probably will se SSL errors being propagated directly to you application though, so you'll need to retry on your own.

I must tell you I've been also seeing SSL renegotiation errors on postgres using Go 1.3 and that's why I've disabled SSL for my internal DB for time being (`sslmode=disable` in the connection string). I was wondering whether version 1.4 has solved the issue, as one thing on changelog was *The crypto/tls package now supports ALPN as defined in RFC 7301* (ALPN states for Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation Extension).